# Any Chess AI for Flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I am looking for any Chess AI for flash CS5 ActionScript 3.

Comment: You could download GNU Chess and port it into ActionScript :p

http://www.gnu.org/software/chess/

Comment: There are good open source Chess AI for C#. Do you think its possible to port them in ActionScript 3? . Wouldn't that be alot of work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[A quick Google search](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=Flash+Chess+source) reveals much of what you're looking for, including good discussions on the basic algorithms involved. If all you're looking for is a solution you can plug into your Chess game, don't expect anything terribly robust, especially if you're looking to [outsmart DeepFritz or Rybka](http://www.husvankempen.de/nunn/rating.htm).

Should you be interested in the process of programming a Chess AI, you might want to read through the [Chess Programming Wiki](http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/).

(As [Drknezz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/528131/drknezz) points out, http://www.gnu.org/software/chess/ is also an excellent point of research for anyone interested in chess engines.)

Answer (score 0):

You can check out my open source chess game project at Github:https://github.com/yangboz/godpaper